# Why does embedded YouTube video have borders on 3 sides in Safari?

Tags: html, css, youtube, dreamweaver

I have an embedded YouTube video on a site I designed. It looks fine in every browser except Safari? I made the video with curved white borders rendered into the movie itself so that once embedded it matches the curves of the container and appears seamless once playing. Have a look at:

http://www.glovesanddoves.com/fighters.htm

In Safari the bottom and both sides of the video have black borders. The code is set to zero out the borders:

```
<iframe width="384" height="216" style="border:none;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GLXrAoNcvXk?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If anyone could find out why this happens and solve this problem I'd be very grateful.

Jack

Comment: It's fine for me http://jsbin.com/emurog/1/edit

Comment: Is this using the flash player or HTML5?  What version of Safari and what version of OSX?  It looks fine to me using the HTML5 player in Safari 6 for Mountain Lion.

Comment: Safari 5 on Snow Leopard look ok for me.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS 10.6.8 and Safari 5.1.7. It still has these borders when I view it? iFrame is an HTML5 tag and as for Flash it's just an embedded YouTube video I uploaded. I have no idea why it does this?